# Base64 Encoded String to byte array C# Failing

Tags: c#, base64, decode

We are receiving a base64 encoded string from a external application in the form body and below is the code that we are using to decode the string into byte array, however we are getting an exception

### Input String

> 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_Jmd0Ow0KJmx0O1RoaXN0bGVDdXN0b21EYXRhIHhtbG5zOnhzZD0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMS9YTUxTY2hlbWEiIHhtbG5zOnhzaT0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMS9YTUxTY2hlbWEtaW5zdGFuY2UiJmd0Ow0KICAmbHQ7T3JkZXJJZCZndDtCVFBQMzYzOSZsdDsvT3JkZXJJZCZndDsNCiAgJmx0O0Ftb3VudCZndDsxMjAmbHQ7L0Ftb3VudCZndDsNCiZsdDsvVGhpc3RsZUN1c3RvbURhdGEmZ3Q7XV0mZ3Q7PC9jdXN0b21EYXRhPjwvcGF5bWVudFJlc3BvbnNlPg

### Exception

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

### Code

```
var inputText = // use the data as shown above
byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputText);
```

I want to know what is wrong in this and why it is throwing the exception, where are if i try online converters they are able to return the proper result.

Comment: The input is bad. If I put it into an [online decoder](https://www.base64decode.org/) I get readable text/xml text up to a point, but then it degenerates into gibberish. It's possible it's mangled by the browser or web server (not correctly http-encoded?)

Comment: The error is accurate. Your base64 text includes at least on underscore (`_`) character, which is invalid. You might try just believing error messages that you get. They are often informative. Replace the `_` with `+` and it will convert correctly. Next time, check your data when you get an error saying your data is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for the response.

I got this working, after studying how the base64 encoding works.

below is the code that i used to fix it.

```
var input = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
        var inputText = "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_Jmd0Ow0KJmx0O1RoaXN0bGVDdXN0b21EYXRhIHhtbG5zOnhzZD0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMS9YTUxTY2hlbWEiIHhtbG5zOnhzaT0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMS9YTUxTY2hlbWEtaW5zdGFuY2UiJmd0Ow0KICAmbHQ7T3JkZXJJZCZndDtCVFBQMzYzOSZsdDsvT3JkZXJJZCZndDsNCiAgJmx0O0Ftb3VudCZndDsxMjAmbHQ7L0Ftb3VudCZndDsNCiZsdDsvVGhpc3RsZUN1c3RvbURhdGEmZ3Q7XV0mZ3Q7PC9jdXN0b21EYXRhPjwvcGF5bWVudFJlc3BvbnNlPg";
        inputText = ValidateBase64EncodedString(inputText);

        byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputText);

        string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedBytes);

       private static string ValidateBase64EncodedString(string inputText)
        {
            string stringToValidate = inputText;
            stringToValidate = stringToValidate.Replace('-', '+'); // 62nd char of encoding
            stringToValidate = stringToValidate.Replace('_', '/'); // 63rd char of encoding
            switch (stringToValidate.Length % 4) // Pad with trailing '='s
            {
                case 0: break; // No pad chars in this case
                case 2: stringToValidate += "=="; break; // Two pad chars
                case 3: stringToValidate += "="; break; // One pad char
                default:
                    throw new System.Exception(
             "Illegal base64url string!");
            }

            return stringToValidate;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your custom data is invalid.
In that Base64 encoded string you have a raw [CDATA] which is most likely not encoded correctly.

notice that if i take the first 684 characters of your string, it converts properly to:

```
<paymentResponse><responseCode>0000</responseCode><responseCodeText>0-Successful</responseCodeText><responseSummary>GREEN</responseSummary><paymentEventIdentifier>TXN 3639</paymentEventIdentifier><List><componentID>TXN 3639</componentID><clientID>GOTDISE06</clientID><bankAuthCode>T:1234</bankAuthCode><buynetTxnID>375</buynetTxnID></List><paymentInstrumentRef></paymentInstrumentRef><maskedCardNumber>************9686</maskedCardNumber><cardType>MASTERCARD</cardType><expiryDate>03/2017</expiryDate><customData>&
```

but all hell breaks loose when we get to the **customData** tag, this I suppose, contains the CDATA xml content, which is probably not base64 encoded.

So either leave the CDATA content out, or encode it properly before adding it to the final string, to fix the issue

Comment: _"this I suppose, contains the CDATA xml content, which is probably not base64 encoded"_ -- you suppose incorrectly. The XML can be (and probably originally was) encoded just fine even with the CDATA section. Base64 doesn't care what the content is; that's why it works. The only problem is that [there's a typo in the base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121665/base64-encoded-string-to-byte-array-c-sharp-failing/40124929#comment67514069_40121665).

Comment: @PeterDuniho your comment is incorrect at its base assumption. the letter count of the string he posted is 1,118 characters long, there is no way you can base64 decode a string if its length is not a multiple of 4. replacing one + with one _ will not solve the issue. the CDATA part is messing up the decoding.

Comment: _"your comment is incorrect at its base assumption"_ -- I assumed nothing. I simply replaced the character as I've indicated, and it decoded fine. It's true that officially, base64 data has to have a character length that's a multiple of 4, but most decoders are tolerant of absent trailing zeroes. The incorrect character length doesn't prevent successful decoding, unless the missing characters were actually non-zero values in the data that got truncated somewhere.

Comment: In any case, whatever you think about the length, and whatever decoder you're using, it is _patently false_ that the CDATA section has anything to do with the issue. Base64 can successfully encode whatever data you want, including CDATA sections in XML. It doesn't care what the content is, because it's just encoding the _binary_ representation of whatever your data is.

Comment: the question was about dot net, so other library tolerance to corrupted input is irrelevant, Convert.FromBase64String() can not work with invalid content. not you nor I know how the string got put together for all we know someone manually typed it. basically we both say the same thing. input was incorrect, I simply pinpointed the fail in the 'customData' tag content. it seems the asker is no longer to be found though so if it worked or not, is still unknown.

Comment: _"I simply pinpointed the fail in the 'customData' tag content"_ -- not true. I wouldn't have even commented if it were. You went beyond indicating the corruption in the output, and made an _incorrect_ statement about the _cause_ of the corruption. As for the question of length, .NET emits the message _"Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string"_ when the problem is the length. Obviously, even without a good [mcve] in the question, based on the error message reported, the OP has passed a correct-length string to .NET (most likely because their code auto-pads the string to an x4 length)